# adding wpf controls dynamically to wrap panel

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm trying to add controls dynamically to a wrap panel on a window but after two wrap panel controls are added to the original wrap panel control it doesn't add anymore here is the code im using to add the image

```
 Random rn = new Random();
 ImageContainer.Children.Add(displayimage(rn.Next(amount)));            
 ImageContainer.InvalidateVisual();
```

im new to wpf and just wondering if im doing something wrong or missing something.

any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

```
        public WrapPanel displayimage(int i)
       {

        WrapPanel pn = new WrapPanel();
        pn.Width = 350;
        pn.Height = 400;
        pn.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePaths[i]));
        Image im = new Image();
        im.Source = bm;
        im.Height = 300;
        im.Width = 400;
        im.Margin = new Thickness(25,25,25,25);
        pn.Children.Add(im);
        pn.Margin = Location(pn);
        pn.ClipToBounds = true;

        return pn;

    }
```

Comment: **Fist:**

if you use the WPF you should use the XAML too, if you don't you miss a impotent thing.

**Second:** 

If i understood this right you try to add controls Dynamic into a `WrapPanel`?that means if you hit the "Add" button there is always another Control that will be add? please explain what exactly you try to do.

Comment: I'm creating trying to add images to my wrap panel in random places on my screen but the most it will ever add is two images the images are added every 5 seconds

Comment: @Venson How do you conclude that there is no XAML? And what Add button are you talking about?

Comment: @RoyJamesSchumacher You would have to add more context to you question. Where is your code called? When you say "every 5 seconds", is there some timer running that calls it? And what does the `displayImage` method look like?

Comment: @Clemens that button was just for example. And i am sure becorse of this code snipping: `ImageContainer.Children.Add`...

Comment: ive added the code for the display image method above

Comment: @RoyJamesSchumacher And where is `ImageContainer.Children.Add` called? Is it inside some loop or in a timer callback?

Comment: And what does `pn.Margin = Location(pn)` do?

Comment: imagecontainer.children.add is called in the time callback and pn.margin = Location(pn) sets the location of the wrap panel based on a random number with a maximum number of 1000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to put images at random places in a container control, you should not use a WrapPanel, but a [Canvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx) instead. Canvas is made for absolute positioning of elements. You set the position of a child element of a Canvas by setting the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties (or `Canvas.Right` or `Canvas.Bottom`).

Moreover you don't need any "inner" panel, as `Image` is a control that can be added directly to any container.

So change your `displayimage` method like this:

```
public UIElement GetDisplayImage(int i)
{
    var bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePaths[i]));
    var im = new Image
    {
        Source = bm,
        Height = 300,
        Width = 400
    };
    var location = Location(im);
    Canvas.SetLeft(im, location.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(im, location.Y);
    return im;
}
```

Now add these Images to a Canvas:

```
Random rn = new Random();
ImageCanvas.Children.Add(GetDisplayImage(rn.Next(amount));
```

The `InvalidateVisual` is not necessary.

---

You might also have to take care that images aren't added multiple times, since `Random.Next` may return the same number multiple times.

Comment: Thank you so much this is doing exactly what i want it to do you have helped a lot, as for the same number being returned multiple times I'm not to worried about that as it I'm allowing my images to overlap as they are added. Thank you again.