# Re arranging controls in WrapPanel at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, wrappanel

I have a WPF `WrapPanel`, it contains some of `Buttons`, I want to re arrange them at runtime. The XAML code at design time like:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <WrapPanel Margin="133,127,216,189" Background="#FF979797">
        <Button Content="Button" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Width="75"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Width="75"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

But, I want to re arrange the `Buttons` at run time. Can you help me about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding}" Width="75"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Items would be a property on your DataContext and would typically be an ObservableCollection of some sort.  In the simplest case, it could be a collection of strings that correspond to the button captions.  When you rearrange the ObservableCollection elements, it will rearrange the corresponding buttons in the ItemsControl, using a WrapPanel to arrange them.

---

On a side note, using this type of approach is a step toward what is known as the MVVM pattern (Model-View-ViewModel.)  This is quickly becoming the industry standard pattern for developing WPF applications and has a lot of advantages when it comes to creating flexible, dynamic UIs.  I highly recommend researching this pattern if you want to do any significant WPF development.  It takes a bit of time to get used to, but it's ultimately quite worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rearrange the children at run time, you have two options, creating (or at least manipulating) the children of the WrapPannel in code instead of XAML, or [setting up Triggers](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522041/Triggers-in-WPF) (in a Style tag) to manipulate the buttons as needed.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428456/adding-wpf-controls-dynamically-to-wrap-panel) an example.